# SharePoint 2010: Send an email to someone based on Form updates to a List

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, form, list-form

I am very new to SharePoint and only started using it this past week (2010 version).

I created a List for workforce updates and would like to be able to automatically send an email through Outlook to a specific person when a List Item is added or modified through a Form.  The person receiving this email will be whoever the user filling out the Form specifies as the "New Manager" on the Form, and hence will be a different person each time.

Can someone please advise me on how to do this / if this is possible?  I am seeing things about using workflows, but I do not believe that I have access to SharePoint Designer to create a new workflow. Is there a way to get around this? Thanks.